# Is there a way to convert a graphql query string into a GraphQLResolveInfo object?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have written a piece of software that parses and formats the fourth parameter of a graphql resolver function (the info object) to be used elsewhere. I would like to write unit tests for this software. Specifically, I do not want to build the `GraphQLResolveInfo` object myself, because doing that would be very cumbersome, error-prone and hard to maintain. Instead, I want to write human-readable query strings and convert them to `GraphQLResolveInfo` objects so I can pass those to my software.

After extensive googling and reading of the `graphql-js` source code, I have not found a simple way to do what they are doing internally. I'm really hoping that I am missing something.

What I am not trying to do is use the `graphql-tag` library, because that just generates an AST which has a very different format from the `GraphQLResolveInfo` type.

Has anyone done this before? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will keep monitoring this question to see if a better answer comes along, but I've finally managed to solve my particular issue by creating as close an approximation of the `GraphQLResolveInfo` object as I need for my particular use case.

The `GraphQLResolveInfo` object is composed of several attributes, two of which are called `fieldNodes` and `fragments`. Both are in fact parts of the same AST that `graphql-tag` generates from a query string. These are the only parts of the `GraphQLResolveInfo` object that concern the software I wrote, the rest of it is ignored.

So here is what I did:

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

// The converter function
const convertQueryToResolveInfo = (query) => {
    const operation = query.definitions
        .find(({ kind }) => kind === 'OperationDefinition');
    const fragments = query.definitions
        .filter(({ kind }) => kind === 'FragmentDefinition')
        .reduce((result, current) => ({
            ...result,
            [current.name.value]: current,
        }), {});

    return {
        fieldNodes: operation.selectionSet.selections,
        fragments,
    };
};

// An example call
const query = gql`
    query {
        foo {
            bar
        }
    }
`;
const info = convertQueryToResolveInfo(query);
```

From the AST generated by `graphql-tag`, I extract and modify the operation and fragment definitions so that they look the way they do within the `GraphQLResolveInfo` object. This is by no means perfect and may be subject to change in the future depending on how my software evolves, but it is a relatively brief solution for my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently to add REST endpoints to my server, since ChatGPT plugins doesn't support GraphQL. Here's what I came up with:

```
import { DocumentNode, FieldNode, FragmentDefinitionNode, GraphQLResolveInfo, OperationDefinitionNode } from "graphql";

const gqlToGraphQLResolveInfo = (query: DocumentNode, path: string): GraphQLResolveInfo => {
    const operation: OperationDefinitionNode | undefined = query.definitions
        .find(({ kind }) => kind === "OperationDefinition") as OperationDefinitionNode;

    const fragmentDefinitions = query.definitions
        .filter(({ kind }) => kind === "FragmentDefinition") as FragmentDefinitionNode[];

    const fragments: { [key: string]: FragmentDefinitionNode } = fragmentDefinitions
        .reduce((result, current: FragmentDefinitionNode) => ({
            ...result,
            [current.name.value]: current,
        }), {});

    const fieldNodes: FieldNode[] = operation?.selectionSet.selections as FieldNode[];

    const resolveInfo: GraphQLResolveInfo = {
        fieldName: fieldNodes[0]?.name.value || "",
        fieldNodes,
        returnType: null,
        parentType: null,
        schema: null,
        fragments,
        rootValue: {},
        operation,
        variableValues: {},
        path: {
            prev: undefined,
            key: path,
        },
    } as any;
    return resolveInfo;
};
```